# Как создать массив с именем из переменной?

Tags: c#, массивы

Хочу создать 1000 массивов в цикле с похожими именами.
Что то типо этого но так не получается так как на сколько я понял нельзя использовать переменные в качестве имени массива.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
{
    int[] (list+i) = new int[10000];  
}
```

На выходе должны получится массивы с именем list0, list1, list2 и тд. 
Как это сделать?

Comment: Может быть вы имеете в виду двумерный массив?

Comment: Нет, именно много массивов. Я сейчас про многопоточность читаю и думал сравнить как быстро создаст массивы и заполнить их случайными числами в один и в несколько потоков, но вот не могу понять как создать сразу много массивов. Эта же ситуация может случится если мне нужно будет ввести имя массива с консоли, оно будет в переменной а как мне создать с этим именем массив я не знаю.

Comment: @User12351259599491 Двумерный массив или массив массивов это и есть много массивов.

Comment: Главный вопрос как создать массив с именем 
`int[] имя = new int[1000]`
из переменной.

Comment: Вы же можете переслать строку двумерного масства, часть линейного и т.п.

Comment: @becouse Совсем не понял о чем Вы) 
Просто хочу узнать как создать массив/переменную/объект с именем из переменной.

Comment: Советую почитать про двумерные массивы. Двумерный это массив массивов.

Comment: @becouse  Серьезна? Вы читали вообще вопрос?

Comment: Зачем вам нужны массивы с определённым именем? Как вы собираетесь использовать их имена?

Comment: @MBo Ну какая разница как я их буду использовать?
Вопрос не в том где и как их использовать, а в том как создать массив/переменную/объект с именем из переменной.

Comment: Создайте свой класс MyArray, в котором будет стандартный массив и свойство с именем :)

Comment: *Ну какая разница как я их буду использовать* — суть в том, что это невозможно вот и все. Когда вы пишете код, вы пишете имена переменных, которые у вас как-то взаимодействуют, вы не можете использовать несуществующие имена, это не допускается компилятором. Для создания набора данных есть коллекции, пользуйтесь ими, если вам важно в вашей логике иметь отдельное имя для вашего набора данных — сделайте его свойством, как я предложил вам в предыдущем комментарии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# строго типизированный язык это значит, что вы не можете создавать динамически переменные. В вашем случае можно использовать коллекцию, например [словарь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.9.php).

Вот пример

```
Dictionary<string, int> names = new Dictionary<string,int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   names.Add(String.Format("list{0}", i.ToString()), i);
}
```

Вот обращение к конкретному массиву.

```
names["list3"];
```